# fpdf - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: php, fpdf

stackoverflow is always helpfull so I hope to find a hand on this.
I'm testing a pdf generated with fpdf on a site. 
When it was running locally with xampp, everything was working great (the pdf was generated including text and images). The content is a collection of favourite posts of wordpress.

But now that I've uploaded it, problems appears. With only one favourite it's ok. The attachment occurs, I download and test it with in adobe reader.
When the favourites are 2 or more, fpdf outputs errors or generate a corrupt pdf..

I know the problem must be related with the images, but I don't understand why..

This is the error(which may happen to several images around the loop):

```
"Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /.../fpdf/fpdf.php on line 1225
```

Warning: getimagesize(...) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /.../fpdf.php on line 1213
FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: ..."

I repeat, locally I did'nt have any problems.
This is the code for output the pdf:

```
$pdf->Output("pdf/".$filename_pdf, 'D');
```

My script is long but if needed you can ask me anything

thanks in advance for any help you can give...
desde ya les agradezco cualquier aporte que puedan realizarme ya que estoy perdido y falto de tiempo!

Comment: somewhere, some resource being added into that pdf is using a url as its file source (`http://...`) instead of a local filesystem reference (`/blah/blah/blah1`) and the dns server handling that host's domain is not responding.

Comment: those resources I think are the wordpress post's image gallery displayed with absolute path (can't change that). When I copy and paste the url, I can see the image.
The strange thing is some post generate the pdf without problem, but others for some reason they don't. Could it be problem with permissions on specific images?

Comment: permissions on a file will not affect dns lookups. could be your domain has multiple dns servers handling it, and one (or more) of those servers is offline/unreachable. if there's multiple servers, dns resolvers will randomly choose one to use.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your web server maybe help you.